# Resharper: How to find usage of a specific implementation of an interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I'm quite often having an issue with the `Find usage` of resharper.

By example, I see that one of my object implements the `IDisposable` interface and I want to go at the place where this `Dispose` method is called.

But if I do `Find usage` or `Inspect incoming call`, it search for all the call to `IDisposable.Dispose` which is not what I'm looking for.

Any advice on how I can find where this specific instance is called? Before there was a `Find usage advanced` but I don't have this option anymore after upgrading to the latest version of resharper.

(I've Resharper V9.0 update 1 and Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: you can search for name `Dispose` in whole solution or project with [search with pattern](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Search_with_Pattern.html). or in VS press `Ctrl + F` and in search textbox type Dispose to search for it

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary ??? It's exactly what I DON'T want, I want to find a specific implementation, not all implementations

Comment: Ok. Sorry if it wasnt helpful. Ill let you know if i find an answer :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nice question. I also had a few times this use case (e.g. for `ToString()` implementation references) but I was always too lazy to look if R# supports this.

The answer is to use the "Find Usages Advanced" feature (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F12) and then select the desired member.

[image: Dialog Screenshot]

Comment: I've to check that, because here(at home, I can find the "Find usage advanced"(even on right click menu), but at work, I'm sure at 90% that I don't have this option anymore.

Comment: Hi. I've just tested it with R# 9.0 U1 and it worked too. Do you have the menu entry ReSharper | Find | Find usages advanced? If not, try to reinstall R#, or maybe try to install R# into an VS experimental instance (see https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Extensions/Deployment/LocalInstallation/ExperimentalInstance.html).

Comment: i just checked, in fact I don't have the "Find usage advanced" in the contextual menu, but I've it under the Resharper menu. It's weird. I'm currently looking why I don't have this option in the menu.

Comment: Well, I just updated to the R#9.0 U2, and it now works, problem solved.

Comment: I could not find it, but after your answer, I tried again and the Search box was 1px high, so  didn't realize that there should be something

Comment: Thank you, I would never have found it if I didn't know it was there! Raised a bug with JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-483356